# Screen width returns negative number

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I want to get the Grid width from my page, so I tried this:

```
public MemeBuilder()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    ColumnWidth = (MainGrid.Width - (8 * 5)) / 7;
    ....
```

But `MainGrid.Width` returns -1.

Here is the xaml of the Grid:

```
<Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="50" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    .....
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "The width of an element is set during the Layout phase" (from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.visualelement.width?view=xamarin-forms)) - My guess is, you could be trying to access it too early.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The best way to handle this is by using Xamarin.Essentials Device Display Information API

```
// Get Metrics
var mainDisplayInfo = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo;

// Orientation (Landscape, Portrait, Square, Unknown)
var orientation = mainDisplayInfo.Orientation;

// Rotation (0, 90, 180, 270)
var rotation = mainDisplayInfo.Rotation;

// Width (in pixels)
var width = mainDisplayInfo.Width;

// Height (in pixels)
var height = mainDisplayInfo.Height;

// Screen density
var density = mainDisplayInfo.Density;
```

Now you can get the width by dividing the density something like:

```
var width = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Width / DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Density;
```

Goodluck

Revert if you have questions

Answer (score 6):

You can subscribe to the `SizeChanged` event and from there get the `Width`:

```
private void MainGrid_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var grid = (Grid)sender;
    var width = grid.Width;
}
```

Comment: @ColeXia-MSFT The questioner was asking his question incorrectly. On the Parent most layout he wanted the width  -_-

Answer (score 1):

My mistake, you are using xamarin form.I think you are not getting the width because of the lifecycle like what @Peter B said.
Either OnStart Event

```
protected override void OnStart()
{
      ColumnWidth = (MainGrid.width- (8 * 5)) / 7;
}
```

or 
Page Appearing Event if your grid is in another page

```
protected async override void OnAppearing()
            {
            if(!isLoaded) 
                {
                //Do API Calls
                isLoaded=true;
                }
        }
```

Comment: "Grid does not contain a definition for ActualWidth"